# jQuery Masonry layout with two specific sizes

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm creating a layout with Masonry that only has two sizes available: a small one and a larger one. However, I created a random selection and they aren't stacking together correctly.

Here is my HTML & JS:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="featured"></div>
   <div class="featured small"></div>
   <div class="featured small"></div>
   <div class="featured"></div>
   <div class="featured small"></div>
   <div class="featured small"></div>
   <div class="featured"></div>
   <div class="featured small"></div>
   <div class="featured small"></div>
   <div class="featured"></div>
   <div class="featured small"></div>
   <div class="featured small"></div>
   <div class="featured small"></div>
   <div class="featured small"></div>
</div>

<script>
docReady( function() {
var $container = $('.container');
   $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
         $container.masonry({
        columnWidth: 225
        itemSelector: '.featured' 
    isFitWidth: true
            });
          });
});
</script>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.container {
  background: #EEE;
  width:960px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.featured {
  width:440px;
  height:440px;
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
  background:#09F;
}

.featured.small{ 
  width:210px;
  height:210px;
}
```

I'd like it if it had the same effect as this site: [Zappos Tweet Wall](http://tweetwall.apps.zappos.com/index.html)

But I'm having trouble grasping how this library works.

Comment: In your JS and CS, you're referencing `container` as a class, but in your HTML, it's the ID

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it but it's still not working right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***Looks fine to me***](http://jsfiddle.net/zDLEm/)

```
var $container = $('#container');
$container.masonry({
    columnWidth: 110,
    itemSelector: '.featured'
});
```

I think it's because of your `imagesLoaded` function.
(Also, it might be because of your `docReady`)

Comment: It definitely had something to do with the docReady function. Because I'm using WP I had to make a jQuery one. Thanks again!